# VBA + read line with quotes from file

Tags: vba, vb6

In the file.txt I have line with quotes as the following

D:\file.txt:

```
    """\\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz"""
```

My target is to read the line from D:\file.txt into pFile parameter

Therefore I write the following simple VBA code:

```
  Dim pFile As String
  Open "D:\file.txt" For Input As #1
  Input #1, pFile
  Close #1

  MsgBox pFile
```

I run my VBA code but From unclear reason pFile not get the content of the line in file,txt
And MsgBox print empty box ?

Please advice why pFile get null ? and what I need to fix in my code in order to put the line from file.txt in pfile parameter

- Remark if I remove the quotes from the line then pfile will get the line from the file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264519.aspx) for `Input #`, it's stated that:

> You should not write strings that contain embedded quotation marks, for example, "1,2""X" for use with the Input # statement: Input # parses this string as two complete and separate strings.

So what is happening here is that your string is being parsed into three separate strings and because you're only using one variable as a parameter for `Input #` then it only contains the first (empty) string. Changing your code slightly to the following:

```
Dim pFile As String
Dim pFile2 As String
Dim pFile3 As String

Open "D:\file.txt" For Input As #1
Input #1, pFile, pFile2, pFile3
Close #1
```

Results in the following:

```
pfile: (empty)
pfile2: \\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz
pfile3: (empty)
```

If you cannot use this, then the alternative could be to use the `Line Input #` statement ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264130.aspx)) which works similarly to `Input #` except that it doesn't delimit lines (i.e. due to commas/separators) like `Input #` does. Code snippet below:

```
Dim pFile As String

Open "D:\file.txt" For Input As #1
Line Input #1, pFile
Close #1
```

Which results in:

```
pfile: """\\server1\pc1\targetG0\source-pc\pkgs.gz"""
```

which you could then modify for your own requirements.

Comment: YES I agree I also +1 for you -:)

Answer (score 4):

I always use Scripting.FileSystemObject for all operations that involve file system, including I/O:

```
Dim fs As Object
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim f As Object
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile("D:\file.txt")
Dim s As String
s = f.ReadLine()
```

The `OpenTextFile` has lot of optional parameters [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), where you can specify if the file is open for reading/writing, if it should be created on access, if it is Unicode (UTF16) etc.

If I run your code on the string you provided, I have the same problem as you. The code with OpenTextFile runs OK though.